# How to add checksum value after insert record using trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, checksum

I am using SQL server 2008. I have a table called document which has file content as `image` datatype. Whenever a new record is added to that table I want to write a `trigger` to create `checksum` for the corresponding file content and the `checksum` column in document table for the newly inserted row should get updated.

I have currently have a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddCheckSum 
ON Document
AFTER INSERT
AS  
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update Document set checksum =  cast(HASHBYTES('MD5', convert(varbinary,i.Content)) As varbinary) FROM inserted i

END
```

But I am getting an error message stating

> Msg 311, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddCheckSum, Line 21 Cannot use
>   text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.

Comment: Your options are refactor column to  `varbinary(max)` or use `INSTEAD OF` trigger

Comment: Can you please give an example to use INSTEAD OF trigger.

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: By using Instead of trigger how I will I calculate checksum for newly created record and insert the checksum value into checksum column in database.

Comment: Show table DDL and sample data INSERT to help others to help you.